# Trapezoid rule for finding coefficient

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, interpolation

If we know that $\int_{a}^b t(x)=h \sum_{k=1}^2 dk * t(a+kh)+O(h^m)$ where $h=\frac{b-a}{3}$, how do we find the coefficient d1, d2 and m in the equation?

Answer says that d1=3/2, d2=3/2, m=3

I tried to substitute x=a+y in the integral, and then expand it in h on the left hand side, expand on the right hand side, then equate them. However got stuck...

$\int_{a}^b t(x) dx=\int_{0}^{b-a} t(a+y) dy$

$=\int_{0}^{b-a} t(a+h)+t'(a+h)*(y-h)+(1/2)*t''(a+h)*(y-h)^2+O((y-h)^3) dy$

$=...$

Could anyone help and be a bit specific please? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try out $t(x)=1$, $t(x)=x$, $t(x)=x^2$ to find conditions that the coefficients must satisfy. Then prove the general order statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $c_1=a+h=\frac{2a+b}3$ and $c_2=a+2h=\frac{a+2b}3$.
Using $t(x)=x-c_1$ one gets
$$
\int_a^bt(x)dx=\frac{b^2-a^2}2-c_1(b-a)=\frac{(b-a)^2}6
$$
and
$$
h(d_1t(c_1)+d_2f(c_2))=hd_2(c_2-c_1)=\frac{b-a}3·d_2\frac{b-a}3=d_2\frac{(b-a)^2}9
$$
giving rise to $d_2=\frac32$. The same goes for $d_1$.

---

Finally explore $t(x)=(x-c_1)(x-c_2)$.

Comment: By setting t(x)=x-c1, it is a specific scenario, not generic, right? Same goes with t(x)=(x-c1)(x-c2), do we have to explore all the possible scenarios?

Comment: Show that all together form a basis of the space of quadratic polynomials.